# "The specified object was not found in the store" error message at appointment binding

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have some problems using EWS. The program subscribes to `PullSubscription` of a certain mailbox. I just want to get the events of the calendar folder. All of them works fine if a certain user books the calendar as a **Resource** but if someone books it as a **Required Attendee** this part throws the following exception:

> "The specified object was not found in the store."

```cs
Appointment ap = Appointment.Bind(_server, eventId);
```

Also if the admin deletes the calendar manually. I do not have any chance to change the Exchange settings so please provide me with a programmatic solution.

Comment: Is the subscription listening to a user-controlled mailbox or a service mailbox? Typically this means the message has been moved - it could just mean a user accepted/rejected the invite.

Comment: sorry what is the difference between a user-controlled mailbox and a service mailbox? The error occurs after I stored the appointment

Comment: User-controlled mailboxes can be administered using Outlook, while service mailboxes are non-interactive and only available through EWS.

Comment: Ah ok. Well in this case the mailboxes are user-controlled mailboxes on which I'm listed as an owner.